# Mirror Maker 2 is not replicating WRITE ACLs for topics and consumer group ACLs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I installed and started Mirror Maker 2 to replicate all possible data from Active cluster to Standby one. It's replicating topics, consumer groups, topic READ ACLs fine, but it is not replicating WRITE ACLs for topics and consumer group ACLs (where resourceType=GROUP) at all, for example:

Current ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern(resourceType=GROUP, name=EquityITIntegration, patternType=LITERAL)`:

```
    (principal=User:EquityITIntegrationSubscriber, host=*, operation=READ, permissionType=ALLOW)
```

Could you please advise why and if there is a way to change this ?

Here are MM2 settings we use:

```
clusters = A, B 

A.bootstrap.servers = s02ap432u:9095, s02ap433u:9095

B.bootstrap.servers = s01ap437u:9100

A->B.enabled = true

B->A.enabled = false

A->B.topics = .*

topics.exclude = kminion-end-to-end, topic.test1

refresh.topics.enabled = true

refresh.topics.interval.seconds = 60

groups = .*

sync.group.offsets.enabled = true

sync.topic.acls.enabled = true

replication.factor=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I also met the same problem,by read mm2 source code,I found the mm2's design is this, so i guass only modify the source code to solve this problem. but i don't know the reason for why to design this